# Return Array to the cell

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

In the below script the the function returns only the final value that is 6 as the return value. Can anybody help me to return the intermediate values also as 3,4,5,6.

```
Function test_array() As Variant

Dim test() As Integer
Dim i As Integer

For i = 0 To 3
   ReDim Preserve test(i)
    test(i) = 3 + i
    test_array = test(i)  
Next i

End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to return the whole array, you just need to modify your line `test_array = test(i)` to `test_array = test` , and put it outside the `For` loop. The reason for that is once `test` array is fully populated inside your `For` loop, you copy it contents to `test_array`, and return it to the calling procedure.

I added a short test Function procedure just to show that all the array results are returned to the calling procedure.

**Function *test_array* Code**

```
Function test_array() As Variant

Dim test() As Integer
Dim i As Integer

For i = 0 To 3
    ReDim Preserve test(i)
    test(i) = 3 + i
Next i
test_array = test

End Function
```

**Sub *Test_Func* Code**

```
Sub Test_Func()

Dim myArr() As Integer
Dim i As Integer

myArr = test_array

For i = LBound(myArr) To UBound(myArr)
    MsgBox "Array element " & i & " value is " & myArr(i)
Next i

End Sub
```

---

**Edit 1**: return all the elements inside the array to the cell (as a `String`):

```
Function test_array() As String

Dim test() As Integer
Dim testStr As String
Dim i As Integer

For i = 0 To 3
    ReDim Preserve test(i)
    test(i) = 3 + i
    If testStr = "" Then
        testStr = test(i)
    Else
        testStr = testStr & "," & test(i)
    End If
Next i
test_array = testStr

End Function
```

Comment: Hi Shai Rado, I dont want it to be called from sub, I need in a function which will directly return the values into the cell. I hope you got my point. your reply will be appreciated.

Comment: how is it suppose to be returned to the cell ? as a String ? like "3,4,5,6" ?

Comment: Yes as "3,4,5,6" to the cell

Comment: Thanks it works, but it gives a error as "Can't find project or library".

Comment: In VBE editor, it opens the Reference Library. not sure why ?

Comment: @HemanthKumar there's no reason, it's not related to the code here, we are not using any `Object`. try resttarting Excel. Or just open a new file, copy only this code and test it.

Answer (score 1):

For having output as 3,4,5,6, you need to create a string array and you can use Join function for the desired output.

PFB for the code. I hope this will help.

```
Function test_array() As String

Dim test() As String
Dim i As Integer

For i = 0 To 3
   ReDim Preserve test(i)
    test(i) = 3 + i
Next i

test_array = Join(test, ",")

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    'Little modification to your code will return all value as comma separated value like "3,4,5,6" in a cell
    Function test_array() As Variant
    Dim test() As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim ret As String
    For i = 0 To 3
       ReDim Preserve test(i)
        test(i) = 3 + i
        ret = ret & "," & test(i)
    Next i
    test_array = ret
    End Function

    Sub test1()
    Cells(1, 1) = test_array()
    'This must produce string "3,4,5,6" in cell A1 of active excel sheet
    End Sub
```